# Как через гугл хром определить, какой скрипт за что отвечает?

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

Ситуация следующая: на странице подключено множество скриптов, мне нужно определить, какой скрипт отвечает за поворот картинки. Как это сделать в хроме или в фаербаге мозилы?

Comment: Читайте комментарии к скриптам, если это библиотеки. Ну и пытайтесь прочитать скрипты, если это кто-то писал до вас. А вообще, можно методом тыка, вырубаете скрипт и смотрите, что отвалилось на сайте. :)

Comment: Как в хроме отключить скрипты через деволопер? Доступа к фтп у меня нет, чтобы я мог вручную убрать...

Answer (score 3):

В Chrome Dev Tools:

Elements → Right Click на элементе → Break On... → Attributes Modifications.

Дальше вызвать поворот, и посмотреть какой скрипт полезет менять аттрибуты элемента.

Comment: А где смотреть?

Comment: @Nredf в окне stack trace

Answer (score 1):

```
ПКМ на элемент, после манипуляции с которым изображение переворачивается -> Inspect Element with Firebug -> HTML (по идее эта вкладка и откроется) -> Events
```

Вам выведутся все события, привязанные к данному элементу, и останется искать нужную функцию, скрипт и разматывать клубок логики.